# Nice spacing for lists in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

In CSS you can independently specify margins for `LI`s and `UL`s or `OL`s. You can also set line-height. In MS Word it looks like you can only specify spacing for paragraphs or list items in general (with an option to remove spacing between consecutive items) along with specifying line spacing (line height).

I want to achieve the following. I would like to have a line spacing of 1, with a spacing of 7pt between each list item, and then a larger spacing, say 12pt, above and below the whole list. That way long list items that wrap to a second line will stay tight with the line spacing of 1, but each list item will have some extra space between them to make it easier to distinguish them. Then the list as a whole will have even more spacing to distinguish it from the main body of text.

I don't care how it is achieved except I am not going to add extra blank lines with a 7pt font size or something. That is just what I am trying to avoid.

Here is an HTML version of what I am trying to accomplish. Notice the three sizes of spacing. https://jsfiddle.net/d6rwxum2/

Comment: Word has had style sheets for decades, now. Since the beginning, you have been able to define your own styles and apply them as needed. Have you looked into this capability?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about. I don't believe you can use CSS style sheets.

Comment: You can't use _CSS_ style sheets, but Word has had its own Style management facility - which has been called several things, including "style sheets" - since at least version 1.1 for DOS, and it still does today. I suggest you investigate the program further, and perhaps purchase a book or three about Word.

Comment: A good start on the research that you failed to do before asking this question would be to submit "style sheets in MS Word" to your favorite search engine.

Comment: So basically you don't know of an answer to my question. The style sheets you are talking about can't do anything other than save and load the styles that you set inside Word. And I believe the term you mean is "style sets". Why would you say that I failed to do research? That is a stupid thing to say.

Comment: Style Sets ("style sheets" in previous versions) can do everything you say you need. That you are asking if there's a way indicates that you _haven't_ done your research, or you would know exactly how style sets/style sheets in Word can help you. Key concept: You are not limited to the named styles that Word provides by default; you can create your own named styles, with the formatting you need, and then apply them to your document.

Comment: StackExchange is not intended to spoon-feed you the answers; doing your own research and showing your finding and where they are inadequate is part of [How to Ask a Good Question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I *have* done my research and I did explain what I tried and why it is inadequate: "In MS Word it looks like you can only specify spacing for paragraphs or list items in general (with an option to remove spacing between consecutive items) along with specifying line spacing (line height)". You obviously have trouble understanding what I am asking for but I don't know how to make it clearer. You think I would just run into a problem and the first thing I would do is ask a question on Superuser? Give me a break.

Comment: What, ***SPECIFICALLY***, do you believe you cannot do using Word's style capability? You can set space-before a list item, you can set space after a list item, you can set line spacing within a list item. What is missing? (Incidentally, it'd help if you indicated what font and font size you're using; if I use sizes that *I* prefer with your settings, it's unreadable.)

Comment: What is missing is setting space before and after the whole list, independently from the space between list items or the space between lines within a single list item. I'm just talking about any normal sort of font like Arial or Times New Roman, 12 or 13pt. I will post a link in the question giving an example of how it should look.

Comment: OK; I'll give you that lack. The best I can offer is that you define _three_ relevant styles; arbitrarily, I'll call them "MyListFirst", "MyListMiddle", and "MyListLast". MyListMiddle defines how you want the individual list items to appear, and is applied to all of the list items, except the first and last. MyListFirst is based on MyListMiddle, and adds the additional space before the first item, and MyListLast is also based on MyListMiddle, and adds the additional space after the last item. Then, apply MyListFirst to the first item, and MyListLast to the last item. Kludgy, but it'll work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no built-in way to make nicely formatted lists in MS Word (or OpenOffice/LibreOffice for that matter). The best you can do, without any fuss, is have the same spacing between list items that you have between regular paragraphs.

If you want less spacing between list items (but full spacing between paragraphs and list items) or if you want to have greater spacing between paragraphs and list items, then you have to fuss.

To simply have less (but still some) spacing between list items, the best I can think of is to set your list paragraph style to have a small amount of spacing after it. Then define an inherited style that has "full size" spacing after it and call that Last List Item, or something. This assumes that your default paragraphs have "full" space after (below) them, but no space before (above).

To just have extra spacing between paragraphs and list items, I think you would need to define styles for First List Item and Last List Item with the extra space.

Answer (score 0):

Create your list, highlight it, then click Paragraph Settings:

[image]

Tick 'Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style', then set your before and after spacing on the left. You're then free to adjust the line spacing as needed on the right.

[image]

Comment: Except I do want spacing between list items.